# Unclear inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I'm making a game in Unity (C#). I created a base class Shape and seven other classes (**FinishStage**, **InfoOnStart** , ...) that inherit from **GameEvent**.

GameEvent:

```
public class GameEvent : MonoBehaviour {
    protected virtual void Start () {}

    public void ResetFields()
    {....
         Reset()
    }

    protected virtual void Reset(){}
}
```

FinishStage:

```
public class FinishStage : GameEvent {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        ResetFields();
   }

    protected override void Reset()
    {
        base.Reset();
        Restart();
    }

    protected void Restart()
    {
        //restart the game
    }

}
```

InfoOnStart:

```
public class InfoOnStart : GameEvent {

    protected override void  Start () {
        base.Start();
        ResetFields();
    }
    /*
    protected override void Reset()
    {
        base.Reset();
    }
    */
}
```

now here is the catch.
in the scene i have 1 instance of **InfoOnStart** and 1 instance of **FinishStage**.

upon start, **InfoOnStart** runs ResetFields().
since it has no ResetFields() and Reser() of its own i expected it to run its parent's ResetFields() and from there the **GameEvent**.Reset().

for some reason however, the **GameEvent**.ResetFields() kept running **FinishStage**.Reset() and thus reloaded the whole scene.

i managed to solve it by writing the

```
protected override void Reset()
{
    base.Reset();
}
```

in the **InfoOnStart** and thus the Reset of **GameEvent** run.

but why has this happened?
why did the parent (**GameEvent**) didn't run its own function but the one on the brother (**FinishStage**)?

Comment: This is unlikely. You call `FinishStage.Reset()`, `FinishStage.ResetFields()` or `FinishStage.OnTriggerEnter` somewhere. Put breakpoints in those methods and debug it.

Comment: I believe it is because you used override. I would need to see how you are instantiating and calling your methods. But, take a look at this article, it may help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Answer (score 1):

because of override "replaces" the Method from the base class. if you want that the base method is also called you have to it explicit via `base.Reset();` within the overriden Method